# How can I use a batch file to list final redirects of a list of URLs?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a list of URLs in a text file that I want read into a batch file and for each URL, the final redirect is output. I have a script that will correctly process one single url, and a script that will loop through the list to print the original URL, but need help combining them to output the redirected URL for every URL in the text file.

Single URL process:

```
curl -Ls -o /dev/null -w %{url_effective} https://www.example.com
```

Output to text file:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=* delims=," %%a in (urls.txt) do (
set URL=%%a
)
echo %URL% >> results.txt
pause
```

I would also like to put a 5 second pause between each URL in the loop, so I don't overload the server. Can someone help me put the pieces together?

Ideally, the output would be like this:

```
https://www.example1.com,https://www.example-redirect.com/page1
https://www.example2.com,https://www.example-redirect.com/page2
https://www.example3.com,https://www.example-redirect.com/page3
https://www.example4.com,https://www.example-redirect.com/page4
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this commented batch file code for thsi task.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem Check the existence of the file in directory of the batch file
rem which should contain the list of urls to process.
if not exist "%~dp0url.txt" (
    echo(
    echo ERROR: File url.txt is missing in directory: "%~dp0"
    echo(
    goto EndBatch
)

rem Delete the errors file on existing from a previous batch file execution.
del "%~dp0Errors.txt" 2>nul

rem Process the list of urls with writing into the results file those urls
rem which are redirected to a different url and into the errors file those
rem urls which could not be processed successfully by curl at all. An
rem existing results file is always overwritten on execution of FOR loop.
(for /F "usebackq delims=" %%I in ("%~dp0url.txt") do (
    set "UrlValid="
    for /F "delims=" %%J in ('curl.exe -Ls -o /dev/null -w %%{url_effective} "%%I" 2^>nul') do (
        set "UrlValid=1"
        if not "%%I" == "%%J" echo %%I,%%J
    )
    if not defined UrlValid >>"%~dp0Errors.txt" echo %%I
    %SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 5 /NOBREAK >nul
)) >"%~dp0Results.txt"

rem Delete the results file if being an empty file. The errors file
rem is created only if there is at least one error with a url.
if exist "%~dp0Results.txt" for %%I in ("%~dp0Results.txt") do if %%~zI == 0 del "%~dp0Results.txt"

:EndBatch
endlocal
```

I don't know what `curl.exe` outputs on using the posted command line because of I don't have this program installed on my computer and don't have read its documentation. I suppose it outputs just the final url. Further I don't know the error output by `curl.exe` on an invalid url or a url on which an error occurs.

Please read the comments of the batch file which are the lines starting with command `rem`.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `call /?` ... explains `%~dp0` ... drive and path of argument 0 which is the full batch file path always ending with a backslash.
- `del /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`
- `timeout /?`

Read the Microsoft documentation about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `>` and `>>` and `2>nul`. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped with caret character `^` on inner **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing inner command **FOR** which executes the embedded `curl.exe` command line with using a separate command process started in background with `%ComSpec% /c` and the command line within `'` appended as additional arguments.

PS: I recommend to take a look on free [Xenu's Link Sleuth](http://home.snafu.de/tilman/xenulink.html).